# Internal Server Error on access via HTTPS to a Django application

Tags: django, https, apache2

I'm trying to make an access to my Django application by HTTPS. 
In the config.py of the project I has set the key

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')

On my configuration to serve all I've an Apache 2.4 so I've create the right entry into "sites-availables" directory, obviously followed by a2ensite, I've generate my own SSL Key (.crt and .key files), changed ownership and permission, restared apache2.
When I try to access to the site I got the follow error message

"""
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

---

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at inno Port 9443
"""

I've take a look into  /var/log/apache2/error.log but there's nothing, on /var/log/apache2/access.log I've found

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [25/May/2016:12:29:36 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico
HTTP/1.1" 500 996 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64;
rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"

There are someone that can give me some hint?

Thanks a lot
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your virtual host within apache isnt properly configured so it's not handling php files the way it should. I guess you should use a handler directive in order to tell apache to handle all .php files and most probably your issue will be fixed. This is the maximum that can be done since you didn't provide much info about the error.

Comment: Sorry, but I use Django, the PYTHON framework. Not PHP. And I coudn't give more details, because I haven't. If you've read, I'd specify that gimme a 500 Http Error, that meaning that can be any problem. And the errors.log doesn't show nothing.